# Antlr4 grammar ambiguity

Tags: antlr4

I have the following grammar ( minimized for SO)

```
grammar Hello;

odataIdentifier  : identifierLeadingCharacter identifierCharacter*; 


identifierLeadingCharacter : Alpha| UNDERSCORE;
identifierCharacter :  identifierLeadingCharacter | Digit;
identifierUnreserved    : identifierCharacter | (MINUS | DOT | TILDE);

Digit  : ZERO_TO_FIVE |[6-9];

ONEHUNDRED_TO_ONEHUNDREDNINETYNINE : '1' Digit Digit;            // 100-199
TWOHUNDRED_TO_TWOHUNDREDFOURTYNINE : '2' ZERO_TO_FOUR Digit;     // 200-249
TWOHUNDREDFIFTY_TO_TWOHUNDREDFIFTYFIVE : '25' ZERO_TO_FIVE;      // 250-255
TEN_TO_NINETYNINE : ONE_TO_NINE Digit;                           // 10-99

ZERO_TO_ONE : [0-1];
ZERO_TO_TWO : ZERO_TO_ONE | [2];
ZERO_TO_THREE : ZERO_TO_TWO | [3];
ZERO_TO_FOUR : ZERO_TO_THREE | [4];
ZERO_TO_FIVE : ZERO_TO_FOUR | [5];

ONE_TO_TWO  : [1-2];
ONE_TO_THREE  : ONE_TO_TWO | [3];
ONE_TO_FOUR  : ONE_TO_THREE | [4]; 
ONE_TO_NINE  : ONE_TO_FOUR | [5-9]; 

Alpha  : [a-zA-Z];

MINUS : [-];
DOT : '.';
UNDERSCORE : '_';
TILDE : '~';

WS  :  (' '|'\r'|'\t'|'\u000C'|'\n') -> skip
    ;
```

for input `c9` it works fine, but when  i have 2 digits for example `c10` it says:

```
extraneous input '92' expecting {<EOF>, Digit, Alpha, '_'}
```

so i guess it parses `9` and parses `2` and doesn't know if this should be `TEN_TO_NINETYNINE` or `2` `Digit` `Digit`.
i am a noob to this, so wondering if my analysis is right and how could i alleviate this ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input is resulting in an `Alpha` token followed by a `TEN_TO_NINETYNINE` token. While the parser rule `identifierLeadingCharacter` does allow the `Alpha` token, the `identifierCharacter` rule cannot match a `TEN_TO_NINETYNINE` token.

The input `10` will always produce a `TEN_TO_NINETYNINE` token rather than two `Digit` tokens, because the former matches more of the input and lexer rules are greedy.