# Dealing with overloaded symbols in ambiguous grammars in ANTLR4

Tags: parsing, prolog, antlr4, answer-set-programming

I am trying to write a parser for a dialect of *Answer Set Programming (ASP)* which, in terms of grammar, looks like *Prolog* with some extensions. 
One extension, for instance is *expansion*, meaning that `fact(1..3).` for instance is expanded in `fact(1). fact(2). fact(3).`. Notice that the language understands `INT` and `FLOAT` numbers and uses `.` also as a terminator.

In some cases the parser fails to distinguish between integers, floats, extensions and separators because I reckon the language is clearly ambiguous. In that cases, I have to explicitly separate tokens with white spaces. Any *Prolog* or *ASP* parser, however, correctly deals with such productions. I read that *ANTLR4* can disambiguate problematic productions autonomously, but probably it needs some help but I don't know how to do! ;-) I read something like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18005972/antlr4-grammar-ambiguity) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21579350/antlr4-lexer-not-resolving-ambiguity-in-grammar-order), but apparently they did not help me.

Could somebody please tell me what to do to overcome this ambiguity?
Please notice that I cannot change the language because it is quite standard.
In order to simplify the experts' work, I created a minimal working example that follows.

```
grammar Test;

program: 
  statement* ;

statement: // DOT is the statement terminator
  range DOT |
  intNum DOT |
  floatNum DOT ;

intNum: // not needed, but helps in TestRig
  INT;

floatNum: // not needed, but helps in TestRig
  FLOAT;

range: // defines an expansion
  INT DOTS INT ;

DOTS: '..';
DOT: '.';

FLOAT: DIGIT+ '.' DIGIT* | '.' DIGIT+ ;
INT: DIGIT+ ;

WS: [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;

fragment NONZERO     : [1-9] ;
fragment DIGIT       : [0] | NONZERO ;
```

I use the following input:

```
1 .
1. .
1.5 .
.5 .
1 .. 5 .

1.
1..
1.5.
.5.
1..5.
```

And I get the following errors which instead are parsed corrected by other tools:

```
line 8:0 extraneous input '1.' expecting '.'
line 11:2 extraneous input '.5' expecting '.'
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this language _really_ accept `1.` as a float? Prolog does not, and this substantially increases the ambiguity of your language.

Comment: @Daniel Lyons I didn't realize that Prolog does not accept `1.` as float... I just took a rather standard definition of floats. Your suggestion, then, is to use the following production for floats: `float: DIGIT+ '.' DIGIT+;`?

Comment: I think that will help and I'd be shocked if it hurt.

Comment: It was as simple as that! Don't know how to flag it as an answer since yours is only a comment...

Comment: It's an answer now. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prolog does not accept `1.` as a float. This feature makes your grammar significantly more ambiguous, so maybe try removing that feature.

Comment: and now it is the accepted answer! Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Before your DOTS rule, add a unique rule for the statement terminal dot and disambiguate the DOTS rule (and change your other rules to use the TERMINAL):

```
TERMINAL: DOT { isTerminal(1) }? ;
DOTS: DOT DOT { !isTerminal(2) }? ;
DOT: '.';
```

where the predicate method simply looks ahead on the _input character stream to see if, at the current token index, the next character is white space. Put something like this in an @member block in your grammar:

```
public boolean isTerminal(int la) {
    int offset = _tokenStartCharIndex + 1 + la;
    String s = _input.getText(Interval.of(offset, offset));
    if (Character.isWhitespace(s.charAt(0))) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

May have to do a bit more work if whitespace is valid between a DOTS and the trailing INT.

Comment: I think I got an intuition of  what you suggest, but I have to do some tests tomorrow to see if I get it right! Thanks for now!

Answer (score 1):

I recommend shifting the work to the parser.

If the lexer can't decide if `1..2` is `1.` `.2` or `1 .. 2` leave if up to the parser.

Maybe there is a context in which it can be interpreted as the first alternative and another context in which it may be interpreted as the second alternative.

Btw: `1..2.` could be interpreted as `1 .. 2 .` (`range`) or as `1. .  2 .` (`floatNum`, `intNum`). How do you want to deal with this?

The following grammar should parse everything. But note that `. .` is treated as `dots` as well as `1  . 23` is a `floatNum`! You can check these tough while parsing or after parsing (depending on whether it should influence the parsing or not).

```
grammar Test;

program: 
  statement* ;

statement: // DOT is the statement terminator
  range DOT |
  intNum DOT |
  floatNum DOT ;

intNum: // not needed, but helps in TestRig
  INT;

floatNum: 
    INT DOT INT? | DOT INT ;

range: // defines an expansion
  INT dots INT ;

dots : DOT DOT;  

DOT: '.';

INT: DIGIT+ ;

WS: [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;

fragment NONZERO     : [1-9] ;
fragment DIGIT       : [0] | NONZERO ;
```